# create hierarchy chart(organisational chart), inputs from the database

Tags: c#, asp.net, oracle, c#-4.0, crystal-reports

[image]

In my web application, I want to create a hierarchy structure in which the inputs are coming from the database. I am using c# and the database is oracle. How can i do this? I searched for this type of graph in crystal reports. But i didn't get anything like this. Please help me.

Comment: does it need to be a report? if not you can give a look to this post http://forums.asp.net/t/1794745.aspx, telerik has to a nice organigram component